# How to start a launch agent on demand after the installation?

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl, launch-daemon, launch-agent

I've coded my launch daemon and a launch agent for macOS. When the app is installed, I need to run both the daemon and the agent. I place the .plist for the deamon into `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and then run (as admin):

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.MyDaemon.plist
```

and since the plist has:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```

the daemon starts up right away.

But I'm struggling to do the same with my launch agent. Here's it's plist that I place into `/Library/LaunchAgents` directory for it to start for every user and also in the login screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>Aqua</string>
        <string>LoginWindow</string>
    </array>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.MyAgent.plist</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.example/MyAgent</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>-d</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

when I try to run it as:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.MyAgent.plist
```

I get an error:

> Warning: Expecting a LaunchDaemons path since the command was ran as
> root. Got LaunchAgents instead. `launchctl bootstrap` is a recommended
> alternative. /Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.MyAgent.plist:
> Path had bad ownership/permissions Load failed: 122: Path had bad
> ownership/permissions

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "**since the command was ran as root**" Have you tried not running `launchctl` as root? Launch agents run in the context of a login session, so running as root is counter-productive.

Comment: @pmdj In that case I'm getting: `Load failed: 5: Input/output error. Try running `launchctl bootstrap` as root for richer errors.`